# S3 cross account access involving 3 accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, amazon-iam

I have 2 AWS accounts (**accountA** and **accountB**). A owns the s3 bucket named bucketA. BucketA is configured as a log storage bucket for one of our CloudFront Distributions. So, the objects in bucketA belong to the **awsdatafeed** account. The ACL of a sample object in this bucket is:

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "awsdatafeeds",
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "awsdatafeeds",
                "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "accountA",
                "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want IAM users in accountB to be able to access the objects in this S3 bucket. So, I followed the instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

I added the following Bucket Policy to bucketA:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1531389545571",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Bucket Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountB:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketA",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketA/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, in accountB, I added the following IAM policy to users:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketA",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketA/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, using the credentials of IAM users in AccountB, I'm able to list the objects in bucketA and also create new objects. But, when I try to get the existing objects belonging in bucketA (whose owner is awsdatafeeds account), I get the following error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

How can I access these log files from AccountB?

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, there are three accounts in this scenario, not two, as is the case in example 2.  See this comment from example 4:

> Bucket owner account can delegate permissions to users in its own account (see Example 3: Bucket Owner Granting Its Users Permissions to Objects It Does Not Own), but it cannot delegate permissions to other AWS accounts, because cross-account delegation is not supported.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example4.html

What you're proposing is two degrees of delegation and this isn't supported.

The account that owns the bucket can copy the objects over the top of themselves, thus taking ownership of the objects and making example 2 work... or the account that owns the bucket can create a role, then both accounts can allow the foreign user to assume that role, with the role having access to the bucket.

An assumed role is like an "identity cloak," hiding the original identity of the entity assuming the role when the role credentials are used for subsequent requests (while leaving a trail at the point where the role was initially assumed), so using a role in this way would not be considered cross-account delegation, and should work as expected.